# Count number of ENTER in TextBox after message selection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I am new to c#. I am learning graphic objects by doing a Hangman game.
I need to save two char arrays : first from the word to be searched in **word_selection_proposal()**, second from the word suggested by the other player in **word_selection_analysis()**.

I was thinking in using a boolean variable named **first** to ensure if that is the first time the function txtWord_KeyPress is called or not, to distinguish the first **ENTER** from the first player to the player who is searching for the word. I understand my boolean is a local variable so it is reset to true each time **ENTER** is pressed.

Is there a possibility to count the number of times **ENTER** is pressed so then I can distinguish which function to call to save the arrays then I could save this data.

Please, see just below the code and a picture to understand the code.
[image: btnWord]
Thank you in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace Hangman_Game
{
    public partial class Hangman : Form
    {
        public Hangman()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Hangman_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillComboLetters();
            comboLetters.Enabled = false;
            btnTest.Enabled = false;
            btnReplay.Enabled = false;
            lblVictory.Text = "";
            txtWord.Text = "Enter a word to search here";
            txtWord.Focus();

        }

        private void FillComboLetters()
        {
            comboLetters.Items.Clear();

            for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
            {
                comboLetters.Items.Add((char)('A' + k));
            }

            comboLetters.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void txtWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtWord.Text = "";
            txtWord.Focus();
        }

        private void txtWord_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Boolean first = true;
            string message = txtWord.Text.ToUpper();
            if ((e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.Enter) && first)
            {
                word_selection_proposal(message);
                first = false;
            }

            if ((e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) && !first)
            {
                word_selection_analysis(message);
                
            }

        }

        private void word_selection_proposal(string word)
        {
            char[] player1 = word.ToCharArray();
            txtWord.Text = "Array copied, Now your turn";
        }

        private void word_selection_analysis(string word)
        {
            char[] player2 = word.ToCharArray();
            txtWord.Text = "array copied";
            txtWord.Focus();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Make `first` a class member, not a local variable (move it outside of the method)

Comment: You can use a second textbox too, and play with `Hide()`/`Show()`